# Follow up: getting frequency count for semi-unique values from a list

Tags: python, ipython, python-3.5

This is a follow up to this question that I asked: [Returning semi-unique values from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497600/returning-semi-unique-values-from-a-list). In short I wanted to turn the list:

```
[a,a,a,b,b,b,a,a,a]
```

into

```
['a','b,'a']
```

User Psidom's answer worked a charm by doing the following:

```
#Paraphrased answer from Psidom

from itertools import groupby  

lst = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','a','a','a']

[k for k, _ in groupby(lst)]
# ['a', 'b', 'a'] #call this TRANSFORM
```

My final goal is to make a pd.DataFrame which has rows=(number of elements in TRANSFORM) and two columns: label, and frequency. My trouble is getting the frequency count for each 'semi-unique' value from the original list, this should be:

```
[3,3,3]
```

Thank you in advance,

Luke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`groupby` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) has this example output:

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

So, I think you need:

```
[(k, len(list(v))) for k, v in groupby(lst)]
```

Which would give you the element and the frequency:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]
```